# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toNumber')

Tags: blockchain, tokens, javascript, ethers.js, solidity-0.8.x

I'm receiving type error please help

Test.js code

```
const { expect } = require("chai");

const toWei = (num) => ethers.utils.parseEther(num.toString())
const fromWei = (num) => ethers.utils.formatEther(num)

describe("MusicNFTMarketplace",function()  // describe() is simply a way to group our tests in Mocha. We can nest our tests in groups as deep as we deem necessary. describe() takes two arguments, the first is the name of the test group, and the second is a callback function.
{
    let nftMarketplace
    let deployer, artist, user1, user2, users;
    let royaltyFee = toWei(0.01);
    let URI = "https://bafybeiba5rxpgfwt6allj5jvr4m2nopo7tswggqzftruuumc3t7gn5wzi4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/"
    let prices = [toWei(1), toWei(2),toWei(3),toWei(4),toWei(5),toWei(6),toWei(7), toWei(8)]
    let deploymentFees = toWei(prices.length * 0.01)
    beforeEach(async function () 
    {
      // Get the ContractFactory and Signers here.
      const NFTMarketplaceFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("MusicNFTMarketplace");
      [deployer, artist, user1, user2, ...users] = await ethers.getSigners();
  
      // Deploy music nft marketplace contract 
      nftMarketplace = await NFTMarketplaceFactory.deploy(
        royaltyFee,
        artist.address,
        prices,
        { value: deploymentFees }
      );
  
    });
  
    describe("Deployment", function () 
    {
  
      it("Should track name, symbol, URI, royalty fee and artist", async function () 
      {
        const nftName = "DAppFi"
        const nftSymbol = "DAPP"
        expect(await nftMarketplace.name()).to.equal(nftName);
        expect(await nftMarketplace.symbol()).to.equal(nftSymbol);
        expect(await nftMarketplace.baseURI()).to.equal(URI);
        expect(await nftMarketplace.royaltyFee()).to.equal(royaltyFee);
        expect(await nftMarketplace.artist()).to.equal(artist.address);
      });

      it("Should mint them list all the music nfts", async function ()
      {
        expect(await nftMarketplace.balanceOf(nftMarketplace.address)).to.equal(8);
        // Get each item from the marketItems array then check fields to ensure they are correct
        await Promise.all(prices.map(async (i, indx) =>
        {
          const item = await nftMarketplace.marketItems(indx)
          expect(item.tokenID).to.equal(indx)
          expect(item.seller).to.equal(deployer.address)
          expect(item.price).to.equal(i)
        }));
      });
      it("Ether balance should equal deployment fees", async function()
      {
        expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(nftMarketplace.address)).to.equal(deploymentFees)
      });
    });
    describe("Updating royalty fee", function()
    {
      it("Only deployer should be able to update royalty fee", async function()
      {
        const fee = toWei(0.02)
        await nftMarketplace.updateRoyaltyFee(fee)
        await expect(
          nftMarketplace.connect(user1).updateRoyaltyFee(fee)
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        expect(await nftMarketplace.royaltyFee()).to.equal(fee);
      });
    });
    describe("Buying tokens", function(){
      it("Should update seller to zero address, transfer NFT, pay seller, pay royalty to artist and emit a MarketItemBought event", async function () {
        const deployerInitalEthBal = await deployer.getBalance()
        const artistInitialEthBal = await artist.getBalance()
        // user1 purchases item.
        await expect(nftMarketplace.connect(user1).buyToken(0, { value: prices[0] }))
          .to.emit(nftMarketplace, "MarketItemBought")
          .withArgs(
            0,
            deployer.address,
            user1.address,
            prices[0]
          )
        const deployerFinalEthBal = await deployer.getBalance()
        const artistFinalEthBal = await artist.getBalance()
        // Item seller should be zero addr
        expect((await nftMarketplace.marketItems(0)).seller).to.equal("0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000")
        // Seller should receive payment for the price of the NFT sold.
        expect(+fromWei(deployerFinalEthBal)).to.equal(+fromWei(prices[0]) + +fromWei(deployerInitalEthBal))
        // Artist should receive royalty
        expect(+fromWei(artistFinalEthBal)).to.equal(+fromWei(royaltyFee) + +fromWei(artistInitialEthBal))
        // The buyer should now own the nft
        expect(await nftMarketplace.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(user1.address);
      })
      it("Should fail when ether amount sent with transaction does not equal asking price", async function(){
        // Fails when ether sent does not equal asking price
        await expect(
          nftMarketplace.connect(user1).buyToken(0, { value: prices[1] })
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Please send the asking price in order to complete the purchase");
      })
    })
    describe("Reselling tokens", function(){
      beforeEach(async function(){
        // user1 purchase an item
        await nftMarketplace.connect(user1).buyToken(0, { value: prices[0] })
      })

      it("Should track resale item, incr. ether bal by royalty fee, transfer NFT to marketplace and emit MarketItemRelisted event", async function(){
        const resaleprice = toWei(2)
        const initMaretBal = await ethers.provider.getBalance(nftMarketplace.address)
        // user1 lists the nft for a price of 2 hoping to flip it and double their money
        await expect(nftMarketplace.connect(user1).resellToken(0, resaleprice, { value: royaltyFee }))
          .to.emit(nftMarketplace, "MarketItemRelisted")
          .withArgs(
            0,
            user1.address,
            resaleprice
          )
          const finalMarketBal = await ethers.provider.getBalance(nftMarketplace.address)
          // Expect final market bal to equal initial + royalty fee
          expect(+fromWei(finalMarketBal)).to.equal(+fromWei(royaltyFee) + +fromWei(initMaretBal))
          // Owner of NFT should now be the marketplace
          expect(await nftMarketplace.ownerOf(0)).to.equal(nftMarketplace.address);
          // Get item from item mapping then check fields to ensure they are correct
          const item = await nftMarketplace.marketItems(0)
          expect(item.tokenID).to.equal(0)
          expect(item.seller).to.equal(user1.address)
          expect(item.price).to.equal(resaleprice)
      });

      it("Should fail if price is set to zero and royalty fee is not paid", async function (){
        await expect(
          nftMarketplace.connect(user1).resellToken(0, 0, { value: royaltyFee })
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Price must be greater than zero");
        await expect(
          nftMarketplace.connect(user1).resellToken(0, toWei(1), { value: 0 })
        ).to.be.revertedWith("Must pay royalty");
      });
    });
    describe("Getter functions", function () {
      let soldItems = [0, 1, 4]
      let ownedByUser1 = [0, 1]
      let ownedByUser2 = [4]
      beforeEach(async function () {
        // user1 purchases item 0.
        await (await nftMarketplace.connect(user1).buyToken(0, { value: prices[0] })).wait();
        // user1 purchases item 1.
        await (await nftMarketplace.connect(user1).buyToken(1, { value: prices[1] })).wait();
        // user2 purchases item 4.
        await (await nftMarketplace.connect(user2).buyToken(4, { value: prices[4] })).wait();
      })
  
      it("getAllUnsoldTokens should fetch all the marketplace items up for sale", async function () {
        const unsoldItems = await nftMarketplace.getAllUnsoldTokens()
        // Check to make sure that all the returned unsoldItems have filtered out the sold items.
        expect(unsoldItems.every(i => !soldItems.some(j => j === i.tokenId.toNumber()))).to.equal(true)
        // Check that the length is correct
        expect(unsoldItems.length === prices.length - soldItems.length).to.equal(true)
      });
      it("getMyTokens should fetch all tokens the user owns", async function () {
        // Get items owned by user1
        let myItems = await nftMarketplace.connect(user1).getMyTokens()
        // Check that the returned my items array is correct
        expect(myItems.every(i => ownedByUser1.some(j => j === i.tokenId.toNumber()))).to.equal(true)
        expect(ownedByUser1.length === myItems.length).to.equal(true)
        // Get items owned by user2
        myItems = await nftMarketplace.connect(user2).getMyTokens()
        // Check that the returned my items array is correct
        expect(myItems.every(i => ownedByUser2.some(j => j === i.tokenId.toNumber()))).to.equal(true)
        expect(ownedByUser2.length === myItems.length).to.equal(true)
      });
    });
})
```

The solidity backend code

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MusicNFTMarketplace is ERC721("DAppFi", "DAPP"), Ownable
{
    string public baseURI = "https://bafybeiba5rxpgfwt6allj5jvr4m2nopo7tswggqzftruuumc3t7gn5wzi4.ipfs.nftstorage.link/";
    string public baseExtension = ".json";
    address public artist;
    uint256 public royaltyFee;

    struct MarketItem
    {
        uint256 tokenID;
        address payable seller;
        uint256 price;
    }
    MarketItem[] public marketItems;

    event MarketItemBought(
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address indexed seller,
        address buyer,
        uint256 price
    );

    event MarketItemRelisted(
        uint256 indexed tokenId,
        address indexed seller,
        uint256 price
    );

    constructor(
        uint256 _royaltyFee,
        address _artist,
        uint256[] memory _prices
    ) payable {
        require(
            _prices.length * _royaltyFee <= msg.value,
            "Deployer must pay royalty fee for each token listed on the marketplace"
        );
        royaltyFee = _royaltyFee;
        artist = _artist;
        for(uint8 i = 0; i < _prices.length; i++)
        {
            require(_prices[i]>0,"Price must be greater than 0");
            _mint(address(this), i);
            marketItems.push(MarketItem(i,payable(msg.sender),_prices[i]));
        }
    }
    /* Updates the royalty fee of the contract */
    function updateRoyaltyFee(uint256 _royaltyFee) external onlyOwner
    {
        royaltyFee = _royaltyFee;
    }
    /* Creates the sale of a music nft listed on the marketplace */
    /* Transfers ownership of the nft, as well as funds between parties */
    function buyToken(uint256 _tokenId) external payable
    {
        uint256 price = marketItems[_tokenId].price;
        address seller = marketItems[_tokenId].seller;
        require(
            msg.value == price,
            "Please send the asking price in order to complete the purchase"
        );
        marketItems[_tokenId].seller = payable(address(0));
        _transfer(address(this), msg.sender, _tokenId);
        payable(artist).transfer(royaltyFee);
        payable(seller).transfer(msg.value);
        emit MarketItemBought(_tokenId, seller, msg.sender, price);
    }
    /* Allows someone to resell their music nft */
    function resellToken(uint256 _tokenId, uint256 _price) external payable{
        require(msg.value == royaltyFee, "Must pay royalty");
        require(_price > 0,"Price must be greater than zero");
        marketItems[_tokenId].price = _price;
        marketItems[_tokenId].seller = payable(msg.sender);

        _transfer(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);
        emit MarketItemRelisted(_tokenId, msg.sender, _price);
    }
    /* Fetches all the tokens currently listed for sale */
    function getAllUnsoldTokens() external view returns (MarketItem[] memory){
        uint256 unsoldCount = balanceOf(address(this));
        MarketItem[] memory tokens = new MarketItem[](unsoldCount);
        uint256 currentIndex;
        for(uint256 i = 0; i < marketItems.length; i++){
            if(marketItems[i].seller != address(0)) {
                tokens[currentIndex] = marketItems[i];
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
        return (tokens);
    }
    /* Fetches all the tokens owned by the user */
    function getMyTokens() external view returns (MarketItem[] memory) {
        uint256 myTokenCount = balanceOf(msg.sender);
        MarketItem[] memory tokens = new MarketItem[](myTokenCount);
        uint256 currentIndex;
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < marketItems.length; i++) {
            if (ownerOf(i) == msg.sender) {
                tokens[currentIndex] = marketItems[i];
                currentIndex++;
            }
        }
        return (tokens);
    }
    /* Internal function that gets the baseURI initialised in the constructor */
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual override returns (string memory){
        return baseURI;
    }
}
```

Please help

Comment: Have you tried [console logging](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_console_log.asp) the variables `i` and `tokenId`?

Comment: Man, you gotta lot of awaits in awaits. You need to pull out an example to share so we can reproduce or at the very least narrow it down to just the test that's giving you problems... You are getting that error because you are calling `toNumber` on some value that does not exist. You need to narrow down your example, give us only the relevant code or better yet, a way for us to recreate the error. Paul there has a really good tip. Also, instead of awaiting inside of awaits, create a var for each value you get! You'll be able to see where you're not getting what you expect that way. Good luck

Comment: https://github.com/Agneeshz/music_NFTs

Here is the complete repo of the project that I made.. I'm not able to debug this... I'll really appreciate it if you could help me fix it... Thank you... @PaulRazvanBerg